Why is node not awaiting?
With node v18, I am trying to loop over an array of directories, and check if that directory is currently on the main git branch. However the await doesn't seem to be doing anything. I often have trouble with promises... what am I missing?
const { promisify } = require('util');
const exec = promisify(require('child_process').exec);

const repos = [
  {name: 'repo1'},
  {name: 'repo2'},
  {name: 'repo3'},
];

repos.forEach(async repo => {
  console.log(`...changing dir to ../${repo.name}`);
  changeDirectory(`../${repo.name}`)
  console.log(`done, current dir is ${process.cwd()}`);

  console.log('...checking if on main branch');
  const isOnMainBranch = await onMainBranch(); // this `await` isnt doing anything
  console.log(isOnMainBranch);
});


async function changeDirectory(path) {
  process.chdir(path);
}

async function onMainBranch() {
  const output = await exec('git branch --show-current')
  const currentBranch = output.stdout.trim();
  return currentBranch === 'main';
}

I would expect the output to be:
...changing dir to ../repo1
done, current dir is /var/www/repo1
...checking if on main branch
true
...changing dir to ../repo2
done, current dir is /var/www/repo2
...checking if on main branch
false
...changing dir to ../repo3
done, current dir is /var/www/repo3
...checking if on main branch
true

but what I get is:
...changing dir to ../repo1
done, current dir is /var/www/repo1
...checking if on main branch
...changing dir to ../repo2
done, current dir is /var/www/repo2
...checking if on main branch
...changing dir to ../repo3
done, current dir is /var/www/repo3
...checking if on main branch
true
false
true


Use normal loop instead of forEach. This function is not async friendly, and won't await after each iteration.

(async function () {
for (let repo of repos) {
console.log(...changing dir to ../${repo.name});
changeDirectory(../${repo.name});
console.log(done, current dir is ${process.cwd()});
console.log("...checking if on main branch");
const isOnMainBranch = await onMainBranch();
console.log(isOnMainBranch);

}
})();
